# jQuery multple button with the same class name is taking only last value

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

In this below `markup` you can see the `class name is same for every button`. I have more number of button with the same class name of button. Now when I am doing click on any button it is taking only the value of `last button value`. Here you can see the `last div` value is `30`. so doing click on every button it is taking only the last value.
 My html markup is like this

```
<div class="cart">
  <div>Qty:
    <input type="text" value="10" size="2" name="quantity">
    <input type="hidden" value="42" size="2" name="product_id">
    &nbsp;<input type="button" class="button-cart" value="Add to Cart">
  </div>
  <div>Qty:
    <input type="text" value="20" size="2" name="quantity">
    <input type="hidden" value="42" size="2" name="product_id">
    &nbsp;<input type="button" class="button-cart" value="Add to Cart">
  </div>
  <div>Qty:
    <input type="text" value="30" size="2" name="quantity">
    <input type="hidden" value="42" size="2" name="product_id">
    &nbsp;<input type="button" class="button-cart" value="Add to Cart">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my jQuery script is like this

```
$('.button-cart').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                //$('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
                setTimeout(opencartpage(),1000);
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the jQuery selector as the data for the AJAX method. That probably doesn't make sense as what you want is name/value pairs (or some other representation of the form fields).

For what I think you want to do (get all the form fields into the AJAX request) the simplest solution is to use the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

If all your fields are in the same form with id `#foobar` than it would be `$('#foobar').serialize()` to return them all back as a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".button-cart").click(
        function()
        {
            var parent_node = $(this).parent("div");
            var quantity = parent_node.find('input[name="quantity"]').val();
            alert(quantity);
        } );
```

Where **this** will identify which class you exactly clicking

Comment: Well, I just show example how to get value by clicking the button. After getting value you can use ur ajax and pass value as you're requirement :)